# how can I uninstall NGINX because it causes havoc with my yahoo homepage

Tags: windows-7, windows, email, nginx

I am using windows 7 for pc.

How can I remove NGINX?  It's interfering with my access to e-mail.

Comment: Are you talking about the web server or the malware?

Answer (score 1):

NGINX is a high-performance web server used by many large websites. Often these sites make extensive use of content caching to improve page load times.

If you are seeing a message similar to *Welcome to nginx* when browsing to your favorite sites, try clearing your internet browser cache.

[Directions for clearing browser cache for most major browsers.](http://kb.iu.edu/data/ahic.html)